# Read text file from input type file

Tags: python, html, flask

I have from and in the form the user can upload files.
I'm using flask, and what im trying to do is to get the data from the text file that the user choose to upload.

There is any way to read the data inside the text file?
I have tried to open the file `file = open()`, but then i realized that i dont have the path.
Its diffrent then reading file on your local machine.

```
@app.route('/admin',methods=['GET','POST'])
def admin_panel():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('adminpanel.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        file_data = request.files['file']
        file_name = secure_filename(file_data.filename)
        file_data.save(os.path.join("system","files","text",file_name))
        with open("system/files/text/file_name") as f:
            file_content = f.read()
            print(file_content)
        file = File(file_data)
        file.read_file_dif()
```

Well of course this code does not working. But thats the idea.
Anyone have any idea how i can read a text file from an input file tag?

**HTML TAG**

```
      <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
      <input type="file" id="myfile" name="file">
```

Comment: Are you able to save the file at the specified location?

Comment: No, Im not even sure that its the correct way to save a file. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to approach is first saving the file and then reading it to get the text. As a convention, you set a `UPLOAD_FOLDER` variable with the path to save. Then, in flask use the following to save the file:

```py
file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(f.filename))
f = request.files['file']
f.save(file_path)
# This would save the file. Now to read simply use the normal way to read files in Python

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
# Rest of the processing logic
```

Note that the path is relative to your current working directory, which is usually the root of your project. Also, please be careful when storing and reading files from untrusted users.

A better place to store these files would be somewhere other than your project root. You could have a data directory somewhere through which you could configure Nginx (or any other front proxy) to serve the uploaded files

Comment: Alright thank you, by the way, do you have any idea why after i import from `werkzeug` the `secure_filename` and run the project. it gives me an error that it cannot import `secure_filename` from `werkzeug`

Comment: You need to import it as `from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename ` . If you want to import it just from werkzeug then you'll need yo reference it as `utils.secure_filename`. I usually prefer the first way

Comment: this import `from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename` worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to my problem

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

class File():
def __init__(self,file):
    self.file = file

def read_file(self):
    file_name = secure_filename(self.file.filename)
    self.file.save(os.path.join("app", "static", file_name))
    with open(f"app/static/{file_name}") as f:
        email_list = f.read().splitlines()
    return email_list
```